# jQuery - saving the content (not just the chosen option) of dropdown lists with form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

What I'm trying to do is save / restore the state of a complex order form.
My form is data driven and has multiple dropdown lists (selects) whose content changes based on various criteria (including choices made in previous dropdown list selections).

While I can find numerous examples (and plugins) on capturing & restoring form data - they all fail in this case because they only store the current selection of the dropdown selection lists, not their contents.

- Saving the current selected option of a dropdown select doesn't work for what I need because that previous selection probably doesn't exist in the current selection list being restored.
- Saving/replacing HTML content visually works but leaves the form dead & non-responsive. I.E. the form looks like the restore has worked but the form can't be updated or submitted because my validation functions fail.

Guidance, code or reference to a valid plug-in would be much appreciated.
If it matters I am currently using jQuery v1.9.1

Thanks...

Edit:
I could just write a backup function where I get each select by its id, get the data & store it and then create a restore function that reverses the process but I was really hoping to find something a little more elegant and less likely to break if I have to modify the order form.
Maybe along the lines of something that serializes the form data but saves & restores the whole select drop list object not just its selected value.

Comment: Hi! I did a cascade select extension for jquery, i don't know if will solve the issue, but its free, and hosted in GitHub, take a look: https://github.com/fals/jquery-cascadeselect

Comment: I'm trying to backup/restore an order form where each product is selected using a set of 5 cascading select boxes.  The problem is not creating the selects or populating them for the form  - the issues is how to backup up the dynamic variable content of the selects and then later restore the form state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid AJAX, you could instantiate your form using JavaScript from data that you articulate in JSON or other markup:

```
form = [
    {
       "question":"Is it the weekend?",
       "choices":["Yes","No"]
    },
    {
       "question":"What will you do today?",
       "options":[
             ["Go to the park","Go to the beach"]
             ["Go to school","Go to work"],
       ]
    }
]
```

Then you could save the appropriate set of choices for each question in persistent storage:

```
localStorage["question2"] = 2;
```

In this case, we've stored that the user selected "No" in the first question, so we want the 2nd choice set for question 2 when we instantiate the form next time:

```
 var options = form[2].options[localStorage["question2"]]
 for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++) {
   $('#select2').append(
      $('<option></option>').val(i).text(options[i]);
   );
 }
```

Comment: As long as Steve Ballmer has relatives, localstorage will not be a 100% compatible solution. (IE 8- )